# I am trying to solve a set of six equations using solve_ivp. The code is taking forever to run and I am unsure if there is a quicker way to do this

Tags: python, scipy

The equations in question are:
[image]

And I defined them in the following function:

```
def lorenz_coupled(sigma = 10, r = 28, b = 8/3, C1 = 1, C1x = 1, S = 0.5, O = -11, C2 = 1, C2x = 1, tau = 0.1):
    def rhs(t, X):
    [sigma * (X[1] - X[0]) - C1 * (S*X[3] - O), r*X[0] - X[1] - X[0]*X[2] + C1 * (S*X[4] - O), X[0]*X[1] - b*X[2] + C1x*S*X[5], (sigma * (X[4] - X[3]) - C2 * (X[0] + O)) * tau, (r*X[3] - X[4] - S*X[3]*X[5] + C2 * (X[1] + O)) * tau, (S*X[3]*X[5] - b*X[5] + C2x*X[2]) * tau]
return rhs
```

where X[0] corresponds to x_1, X[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWXUz.png) = y_1, X[2] = z_1, X[3] = x_2, X[4] = y_2, and X[5] = z_2.

And then try to solve the system of equations with solve_ivp, in the following way:

```
#Initial conditions
X0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

#maiximum time
t_max = 20
t = np.linspace(0, t_max, 10*t_max + 1)
#solve function
rhs_fun = lorenz_coupled(sigma = 10, r = 28, b = 8/3, C1 = 1, C1x = 1, S = 0.5, O = -11, C2 = 1, C2x = 1, tau = 0.1)
sol6 = solve_ivp(rhs_fun, (0, t_max), X0, t_eval=t)
```

But this takes forever to run and has never given me any output. Is there another way to do this that would be quicker?

Also, ideally I would want to run this up until t_max = 5000 or so, but it can't even run for 20 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your problem is sufficiently stiff that RK45 (the default solver) is having trouble.  Have you tried alternative timestepping schemes?  The [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) suggests

> If it makes unusually many iterations, diverges, or fails, your problem is likely to be stiff and you should use ‘Radau’ or ‘BDF’. ‘LSODA’ can also be a good universal choice, but it might be somewhat less convenient to work with as it wraps old Fortran code.
> You can also pass an arbitrary class derived from OdeSolver which implements the solver.

You could also try vectorizing your rhs evaluation function and setting the `vectorized` flag to `True`.  This should increase performance.  Supplying an exact Jacobian should also be fairly straightforward for this problem and would cut the number of calls to your rhs function by about an order of magnitude.